# Qgis Plugin DataPlotly (Ubuntu) : 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pandas, dataplotly

I work with Qgis 3.34.0-Prizren on Ubuntu.
I would like test and use the qgis DataPlotly plugin.
I succeed in installing this plugin via the qgis plugin manager. But when i try to enable it still into the plugin manager, i have an error message saying :

```
Impossible de charger l'extension 'DataPlotly' provoque une erreur lors de l'appel à sa méthode classFactory()

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 423, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/DataPlotly/__init__.py", line 33, in classFactory
    from .data_plotly import DataPlotly
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/DataPlotly/data_plotly.py", line 36, in
    from DataPlotly.processing.dataplotly_provider import DataPlotlyProvider
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/DataPlotly/processing/dataplotly_provider.py", line 24, in
    from DataPlotly.processing.dataplotly_scatterplot import DataPlotlyProcessingScatterPlot
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/DataPlotly/processing/dataplotly_scatterplot.py", line 43, in
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'**


Version de Python : 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0]
Version de QGIS : 3.34.0-Prizren Prizren, ffbdd678812

Chemin Python :
/usr/share/qgis/python
/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins
/usr/lib/python310.zip
/usr/lib/python3.10
/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/HCMGIS/forms
/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SentinelHub/external/requests_oauthlib-1.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/go2streetview
/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/go2streetview/res
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know which version of Ubuntu you are referring to. I assume you installed QGIS via *apt*, but we also don't know how your */etc/apt/sources.list* and */etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources* files are configured.

If you wanted to, you would always find a way to break one package by wanting to install another. However, the safest way to prevent that from happening seems to me to be the following:

Update apt lists:
`sudo apt update`

Install aptitude:
`sudo apt install aptitude`

Install *python3-pandas* package:
`sudo aptitude install python3-pandas`